How do I completely self-sign (or remove existing signature) driver which is signed by revoked certificate?
I have a driver signed by Chinese company from Beijing, let's call it a HackDriver. Microsoft cannot verify authority of certificate because it has been revoked and Windows cannot work with that certificate so a desired device won't start. I'd like to completely re-sign that driver, or even remove a signature from that driver. I have hackdriver.ini file, hackdriver.sys file and hackdriver.cat file for driver. I installed Windows Kit and I used signtool remove /s /v hackdriver.sys. I see that signature was removed. When I install that driver for device I see that it still shows a bad signature in properties of object in Device manager. I assume that I removed driver signature but it is still there.
So, how do I completely remove driver signature?

I found detailed answer here: remontka.pro/sign-driver-windows . It worked for me
